# JBWEB000289 JBoss Error while Deployment

Tags: java, jboss, activemq-classic

I am getting following error. I do not how & why some servlet expects ActiveMQ service at startup. I yet to do code walk through. I have started the ActiveMQ service now. I hope I won't getting the error in next deployment.

I have posted one answer how to install & start Apache ActiveMQ service....

```
12:01:37,320 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/aggt]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 119) JBWEB000289: Servlet aggregatormo threw load() exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Initialise MO Consumer Failed : <Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61615. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect>
    at com.singtel.pcb.aggregator.servlet.AggregatorMOServlet.init(AggregatorMOServlet.java:79) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3593) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3802) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download ActiveMQ from Apache

Say for example ActiveMQ 5.11.1 which is latest stable version as of now

set JAVA_HOME to JDK 7 (Major version 51.0)

```
C:\apache-activemq-5.11.1\bin>activemq start
```

Try deploy the application again.

If your application expects service on another port from ActiveMQ, then configure activemq.conf accordingly and run service on that port.

I am not much aware of ActiveMQ messaging protocols. All I knew it supports set of Messaging protocols. And ActiveMQ is JMS compliance Messaging system.

About openwire,- service runs on port `61616`, here is an excerpt from Apache site....

> An OpenWire JMS producer can send messages to a Stomp consumer, and a Stomp producer can send messages to an OpenWire JMS consumer.